# Presenting custom ViewController class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to present a SwiftyCam view controller (https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam) but am getting SIGABRT errors when trying to present it. I assume it's because the class is type `SwiftyCamViewController` instead of `UIViewController`, how can I present the view controller without crashing?

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoTapingVC") as! VideoTapingVC
self.present(vc, animated: true)

class VideoTapingVC: SwiftyCamViewController, SwiftyCamViewControllerDelegate {
    
    let captureButton = SwiftyCamButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 70, height: 70))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        captureButton.delegate = self
        defaultCamera = .front
        doubleTapCameraSwitch = true
    }
    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didBeginRecordingVideo camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
        
    }
    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didSwitchCameras camera: SwiftyCamViewController.CameraSelection) {
    }
    func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFinishProcessVideoAt url: URL) {
    }
}
```

this is the error when trying to present:

`Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1e882f178) to 'databaseProject.VideoTapingVC' (0x10487f290).`

Comment: SwiftyCamViewController should inherit from UIViewController (otherwise the project wouldn't have compiled), so you are presenting a UIViewController. Are there any other logs that are printed/errors that could provide more details? The error could be anything - for example, storyboard linking issues.

Comment: Could you please share the exact error message that Xcode give you?

Comment: I edited with the error message. The code works fine when presenting a normal view controller

Answer (score 2):

The error message describes a UIViewController. I believe this is because you forgot to enter the view controller type in the Identity inspector in the storyboard.

Comment: that is exactly what happened, stupid mistake on my part

Comment: The mistake was not _reading the error message_ to yourself. Trust me, we've _all_ made the mistake where you don't enter the class in the identity inspector. :) (You know, like once a week.)